# Visio VBA Cell argument HorizAlign throwing error

Tags: python, vba, visio, pywin32

I need to left-align text in a Visio shape programatically using Python 2.7 and the Pywin32 package.

I am able to use the VerticalAlign argument without problem; however, the [HorizAlign](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767743.aspx) argument causes the pywin32 package to throw the error below.

```
scheduleShape.CellsU("HorizAlign").FormulaU = '0'
File "<COMObject Drop>", line 2, in CellsU
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Drawing10 - 
Visio Professional', u'\n\nUnexpected end of file.', None, 0, -2032466967), None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because cell name is not "HorzAlign" but "Para.HorzAlign". Check the docs at the link, "cell name". Should work:

```
scheduleShape.CellsU("Para.HorzAlign").FormulaU = '0'
```

Comment: less the 'i', as @Nikolay has it in the text.

Comment: Yep. fixed the answer - it's turned out to be a bit more tricky than expected :)